# How can I find all solutions/routes in a graph and how to get the optimal one?

Tags: c#, search, graph

so I have a college assignment where there is a graph and each vortex is looked at as a city, each city has quests in it (any number of quests, and they are stored in linked lists) and each quest has money and dangerLevel attributes. My job is to find the best route where I get the most money and with the least possible dangerLevel. travelling from city to city takes one day and completing a quest also takes a day, the user can give how many days to work with.

I was thinking about backtracking through the graph but I'm not even sure if that's the easiest way.

Any suggestions? Or can somebody help how to apply backtarcking in a graph where each vortex has sublevels.

**Graph class:**

```
class Graph
    {
        List<Cities> Cities;
        List<List<Edge>> Neigbours;

        public class Edge
        {
            public Cities to;
            public int weight;
            public Edge()
            {
                weight= 1;
            }
        }
```

**Cities class:**

```
class Cities
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public LinkedList Quests { get; set; }

}
```

**Contracts/quests class:**

```
class Contract
{
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public int Price { get; set; }
    public int DangerLevel { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You need to use Dijkstra's algorithm and try every combination to get shortest path.

Comment: It's very unlikely that they'd ask you to solve this without previously covering how to go about doing so, like the mentioned Dijkstra's algorithm.

Comment: @insane_developer Well they gave us the problem and we are supposed to figure it out on our own. Though it's true that Dijkstra's algorithm is a topic in the curriculum. I will try that thanks.